# RDF triples to a table

Tags: sparql, rdf, triples

I have a triple store with RDF triples and I want to export the data to a table where columns represent the predicates. For example, if I have the following triples

```
:s1 :p1 "v11"
:s1 :p2 "v12"
:s2 :p2 "v22"
:s2 :p3 "v23"
```

I want it to be as follows

```
----|  p1    | p2  | p3
s1  |  v11   | v12 | (null)
s2  | (null) | v22 | v23
```

This might seems a little odd, as in most cases we need to export the other way but here I want to feed this data into a data mining software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**USE OPTIONAL**

If you know the predicates in advance, you can wrap each predicate in OPTIONAL to get all predicates in the same row for all subjects - even if some are missing. Here is an [example](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=SELECT+%3Fname+%3Fbirth+%3Fdeath%0D%0AWHERE+%7B%0D%0A%3Fperson+foaf%3Aname+%3Fname+.%0D%0A%3Fperson+dbo%3AbirthPlace+%3ABerlin+.%0D%0A%0D%0AOPTIONAL+%7B+%3Fperson+dbo%3AbirthDate+%3Fbirth+.+%7D%0D%0AOPTIONAL+%7B+%3Fperson+dbo%3AdeathDate+%3Fdeath+.%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AORDER+BY+%3Fname%0D%0ALIMIT+1000):

```
SELECT ?name ?birth ?death
WHERE {
?person foaf:name ?name .
?person dbo:birthPlace :Berlin .
OPTIONAL { ?person dbo:birthDate ?birth . }
OPTIONAL { ?person dbo:deathDate ?death .}
}
ORDER BY ?name
LIMIT 1000
```

I keep my original answer for reference:

**Use UNION (creates separate rows for each predicate)**

If you know the predicates in advance, you can use UNION to get all predicates for all subjects - even if some are missing. Here is an [example](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=SELECT%20%3Fname%20%3Fbirth%20%3Ffield%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%3Fperson%20foaf%3Aname%20%3Fname%20.%0D%0A%3Fperson%20dbo%3AbirthPlace%20%3ABerlin%20.%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%3Fperson%20dbo%3AbirthDate%20%3Fbirth%20.%0D%0A%7D%20UNION%20%7B%0D%0A%3Fperson%20dbo%3Afield%20%3Ffield%20.%0D%0A%7D%7D%0D%0AORDER%20BY%20%3Fname%0D%0ALIMIT%20100%0D%0A%0D%0A):

```
SELECT ?name ?birth ?field
WHERE {
?person foaf:name ?name .
?person dbo:birthPlace :Berlin .
{
?person dbo:birthDate ?birth .
} UNION {
?person dbo:field ?field .
}}
ORDER BY ?name
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Thanks @René, but in your example I see that each value has a separate row (e.g. "Agnete Bræstrup"), and I was thinking of a way to export the whole graph. And yes, I don't have multiple values for each predicate.

Comment: @Mostafaabdo  
I updated my answer with a solution which keeps everything in one row.

Comment: All credits for @René, and here it is a 'modified' version to export all predicates (of course to be use with 'limited' graph).

get all predicates
`SELECT DISTINCT ?p
WHERE {
   ?s ?p ?o
  }`

Export them to excel and use concat function to assemble query as in the original answer.